# Lottery sollidity

Tags: solidity

i follow the book "Building games with Ethereum smart contracts_ intermediate projects for Solidity developers (2018, Apress)" but the code didn't work

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract RecurringLottery {

    struct Round {
        uint endBlock;
        uint drawBlock;
        Entry[] entries;
        uint totalQuantity;
        address winner;
    }

    struct Entry {
        address buyer;
        uint quantity;
    }

    uint constant public TICKET_PRICE = 1e15;

    mapping(uint => Round) public rounds;
    uint public round;
    uint public duration;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;

    // duration is in blocks. 1 day = ~5500 block
    function RecurringLottery (uint _duration) public {
        duration = _duration;
        round = 1;
        rounds[round].endBlock = block.number + duration;
        rounds[round].drawBlock = block.number + duration + 5;
    }

    function buy () payable public {
        require(msg.value % TICKET_PRICE == 0);

        if (block.number > rounds[round].endBlock) {
            round += 1;
            rounds[round].endBlock = block.number + duration;
            rounds[round].drawBlock = block.number + duration + 5;
        }

        uint quantity = msg.value / TICKET_PRICE;
        Entry memory entry = Entry(msg.sender, quantity);
        rounds[round].entries.push(entry);
        rounds[round].totalQuantity += quantity;
    }

    function drawWinner (uint roundNumber) public {
        Round storage drawing = rounds[roundNumber];
        require(drawing.winner == address(0));
        require(block.number > drawing.drawBlock);
        require(drawing.entries.length > 0);

        // pick winner
        bytes32 rand = keccak256(
            block.blockhash(drawing.drawBlock)
        );
        uint counter = uint(rand) % drawing.totalQuantity;
        for (uint i=0; i < drawing.entries.length; i++) {
            uint quantity = drawing.entries[i].quantity;
            if (quantity > counter) {
                drawing.winner = drawing.entries[i].buyer;
                break;
            }
            else counter -= quantity;
        }

        balances[drawing.winner] += TICKET_PRICE * drawing.totalQuantity;
    }

    function withdraw () public {
        uint amount = balances[msg.sender];
        balances[msg.sender] = 0;
        msg.sender.transfer(amount);
    }

    function deleteRound (uint _round) public {
        require(block.number > rounds[_round].drawBlock + 100);
        require(rounds[_round].winner != address(0));
        delete rounds[_round];
    }

    function () payable public {
        buy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I've used the exact same book :) and it seems like the smart contract is working for me, perhaps this is an incompatible older version of solc? I think I'm using the latest one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://remix.ethereum.org to quickly verify what is not correct. Your posted code compiles but shows couple of warnings. So you might want to add "what" exactly doesn't work

Comment: i run draw winner function a it show "transact to RecurringLottery.drawWinner errored: VM error: revert.
revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value. Debug the transaction to get more information"